# Cypress: How to handle window popup authentication while clicking on link which open another subdomain link?

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

In Cypress we can handle window popup authentication while visiting a url like this

Step:1

```
cy.visit(https://username:password@uk.myapp.com)
```

This is working fine.
But my scenario is after performing Step:1 we need to click on an element which navigates to other sub domain url

```
us.myapp.com
```

but this time after clicking on element and navigating to sub domain it asks again for window popup authentication.
At this time we are not visiting url so we can't pass window popup auth like below

```
cy.visit(https://username:password@us.myapp.com)
```

How we can tackle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `cy.intercept()` to inject the parameters into the outgoing request.

Presuming that  `https://username:password@us.myapp.com` works for the second domain, it would be something like this,

```js
const username = ...
const password = ...

cy.intercept('https://us.myapp.com/**', (req) => {
  req.url = `https://${username}:${password}@us.myapp.com`;
  req.continue()
})
```

Comment: Via intercepting Api call, it still stuck on asking for window popup authentication, and after 60 seconds failing test case.
Api call is correct but it's making call after providing credentials.

Comment: You would need to stop the UI prompting, which means you need to find out why it's prompting and change that. It could be cookies, localstorage, session data, or properties on the window object - you will need more information to solve that issue.

Comment: In any case, you will still need to intercept and update the request.

Comment: Yes this is the main challenge to find the stuff which is responsible to open UI Prompt, I tried to investigate in cookies and (any token ) in local storage.. But couldn't find anything.